# Microsoft Azure Canada Hosting

Tags: azure

Working with a real estate customer of mine selling our Xerox DocuShare Flex platform which is hosted by Microsoft Azure.

Customer is seeing that the data is stored globally on our Xerox Docushare Flex website. Client is saying the data can only be stored in Ontario Canada for them to look at it. The Microsoft Azure website shows Toronto Canada but customer needs to be assured the data will only be stored at the Toronto location.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/global-infrastructure/locations/

Can you advise or direct me to someone that can advise on this? Thank you.

Nathan

Comment: Are you asking us where the data on your server is stored in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy resources in Azure they will generally be deployed in a the region you select. However, there is a reason Microsoft call it "Canada East" and not Toronto, there is no guarantee the data will stay within the Toronto area. Microsoft will guarantee that the data will stay within Canada, but not a specific part of the country.

If you use Geo-Replicated services such as GRS storage, or Azure SQL Geo replication then your data will replicate to the other Canadian region.